# Is "Cannot be taken to be true" common in American English?

Tags: phrase-meaning

In a final paragraph of my essay in Toefl exam, I want to say an statement which means "the conclusion in first paragraph (which is a reasoning of an author) is false".

Can I say instead that "the conclusion in first paragraph cannot be taken to be true"?

The reason that I want to use the second one is that I think the second one is more beautiful and I want to impress the examiner.

If it is true, and if I use "cannot be taken to be true", is it a common sentence?

If not, What else can I say?

Comment: Is there any reason you don't want to go with what (I at least think) is the obvious option? "It is false".

Comment: Sorry, I was vague. I explained what I wanted to ask.

Comment: Your edit still hasn't explained what's wrong with the simpler original statement you give: *the conclusion in the first paragraph is false.* Why complicate things? Note that your revision doesn't actually say that it's false. (So it doesn't have the same meaning.) It actually says that nobody could *consider or conclude* that it's true. That's something altogether different; you can't say it *instead* while preserving the original meaning—although you could say it additionally if you wanted to.

Comment: @Jason Bassford: I revised the question again.

Comment: Again, though, it has a completely different meaning. If you are trying to tell an examiner that a conclusion is false, your revision doesn't do that. (If you remove *taken* it would be more accurate—but still not as simple or direct.)

Comment: "taken" here is a little vague.  A verb like "considered" or "presumed" would most certainly be a better fit here.  Or perhaps a more simplified version like, "cannot be true" would work fine as well.

Comment: @Saeed As a general principle, one is unlikely to impress an examiner by using six words when one will do. Brevity is a virtue.

Comment: @RonaldSole Brevity is the soul of wit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reasoning is not true of false. Assertions are true or false.

You can say that the argument or the reasoning is **flawed**.

You can say that the conclusion is **unwarranted**.